# Differentiation of multivariable function proof

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, definite-integrals

I'm looking for the differentiation of multivariable function integral $$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \int_{v(x)}^{u(x)}f(t,x)dt=u'(x)f(u(x),x)-v'(x)f(v(x),x)+\int_{v(x)}^{u(x)}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(t,x)dt$$ 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Start with 
$$I(x)=\int^u_vf(t,x)\;\mathrm dt=F(u,x)-F(v,x)$$
Where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$.
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}I=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}F(u,x)-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}F(v,x)
$$

Now for a function $w(a(x),b(x))$ its derivative with respect to $x$ can be written as 
$$\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}(x)\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}(a(x),b(x))+\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}(x)\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}(a(x),b(x))$$

In terms of $F$ we have $F(u,x)$ and $F(v,x)$ which remember $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x$. Therefore for each of them we can write this by plugging into the above formula. $w(x)=F(x)$, $a(x)=v(x)\;\mathrm{or}\; u(x)$ and $b(x)=x$.

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}F(v,x)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}f(v,x)+\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}f(v,x)$$because $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=1$. Now the above also holds for $F(u,x)$ so $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}F(u,x)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}f(u,x)+\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}f(u,x)$$

Therefore $$I'=f(v,x)+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}f(v,x)-f(u,x)-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}f(u,x)$$
Now rearranging you can see that it starts to take on your form.
$$I'=v'f(v,x)-u'f(u,x)+f(v,x)-f(u,x)$$
Now the last two terms can be written in terms of an integral.
$$f(v,x)-f(u,x)=\int^v_uf'(t,x)\;\mathrm dt$$
Which then can all come together to give 
$$I'=v'f(v,x)-u'f(u,x)+\int^v_u \frac\partial{\partial x} f(t,x)\;\mathrm dt\\ \implies \frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int^u_vf(t,x)\;\mathrm dt=v'f(v,x)-u'f(u,x)+\int^v_u \frac\partial{\partial x} f(t,x)\; \mathrm dt$$
Which is the formula you want to prove.